# Why is my nested IF condition not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if record exists and if it does then go to page A, otherwise go to page B. But it just always goes to page A whether there is a record or not.

```
<?php
$ini = parse_ini_file("../phpconfig.ini");

$conn = mysqli_connect($ini['hostaddress'], $ini['username'], $ini['password'], $ini['databasename']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$options = ['cost' => 10,];

$number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['number']);
$password = password_hash((mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password'])), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$sql = "INSERT INTO usertemp (Employee_Number, Password)
VALUES ('$number', '$password')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    $sql2 = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM employee WHERE Number = '$number')";
    $row2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($row2) > 0) {
            //Has record in Employee table
            header("location: display_createaccount_a.php");
        } else {
            //No record in Employee table
            header("location: display_createaccount_b.php");
        }

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: The salt option for the password_hash() function has been deprecated so that the developers do not generate their own (usually insecure) salts. The function itself generates a cryptographically secure salt, when no salt is provided by the developer - thus custom salt generation is not required any more. PHP 7, at somepoint u will need to upgrade to that version, better start following its guidelines

Comment: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT EXISTS(...)` is always going to return 1 row with true or false.

In this case, read the first index of the result and use that as your conditional value.

or better yet, use `LIMIT` instead and keep your app logic as it is:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Number = '$number' LIMIT 1";
```

Also, I recommend checking out the [PHP documents](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) on prepared statements.  This is a safer way of querying mysql.